# android remote database best way to encrypt password column

Tags: android, sql, database

so i have an app which connects to a remote database (on the web) using JSON, it contains some user info including passwords, and i was wondering what is the best practice to encrypt the user password so that they can safely be stored to a database

Answer (score 0):

SHA1 should be good unless youre doing something important

Comment: well its `sha1()` method call in php